# Combine code to attach pdf and screenshot

Tags: excel, vba

I have two pieces of code that work independently.

I would like to add a button to my sheet to do both. In other words to create the email with the screenshot generated by ScreenShotResults4() and attach the pdf generated by PrintPIP_To_PDF().

I tried combining but got syntax errors. I cobble code together with the help of sites like this.

```vb
Public Sub ScreenShotResults4()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim Email As Object
    Dim Sht As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Set rng = Sheets("Summary").Range("B21:N37")
    rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Email = olApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set wdDoc = Email.GetInspector.WordEditor
    
    'strbody = "See production data for most recent 3 months.  "
    
    With Email
        .To = Worksheets("Summary").Range("B21").Value
        .Subject = "12 Month LO Production Lookback for " & Worksheets("Summary").Range("B21").Value & " (" & Worksheets("Summary").Range("B23").Value & "- " & Worksheets("Summary").Range("B35").Value & ")"
        '.HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:12.5pt;font-family:Calibri>" & "</p>" & strbody & RangetoHTML(rng) & Signature
        .Display
        
        wdDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture
    
        'if need setup inlineshapes hight & width
        With wdDoc.Content
            '--- paste the range image first, because it overwrites
            '    everything in the document
            .PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture
    
            '--- now add our greeting at the start of the email
            .InsertBefore "See 12 month production data. " & vbCr & vbCr
                               
            '--- finally add our sign off after the image
            .InsertAfter vbCr & _
               "Thank you" & vbCr & vbCr   
        End With

        .Display
    End With
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    
    Set Email = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub

Sub PrintPIP_To_PDF()
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Mortgage1"
    Dim PrintRng As Range
    Dim pdfile As String
    'Setting range to be printed
    Set PrintRng = Worksheets("PIP").Range("B3:M27")
    'Range("B25:C25").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    sPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\"
    pdfile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
      (InitialFileName:=sPath & "PIP" & " " & Worksheets("Summary").Range("B21").Value, _
      FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
      Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")
    Filename = pdfile
    If Filename = False Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        PrintRng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
          Filename:=pdfile, _
          Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
          IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
          IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
          OpenAfterPublish:=False
        Call MsgBox(pdfile & " file has been saved!")
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Mortgage1"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `I tried combining` please post that.

Answer (score 0):

pls try this.
after displaying draft email `.Display`
use `.Attachment.Add "C:\Test.pdf"`

also if u wish to, u can save a copy of draft email (before sending) using
`.SaveAs "C:\OutLookDrafts\Draft1.msg"`